# Angular : Load JIT compiled Dynamic module in root module

Tags: angular, routes

I have generated a JIT compiled module but not able to load it in root module. Any help will be greatly appreciated.. It's my third day now on this problem

JIT compiled Module - dynaModule

```
let dynaModule = NgModule({
        declarations: dyna_comps,
        exports: dyna_comps,
        imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: 'cc1',
                component: dyna_comps[0]
            },
            {
                path: 'cc2',
                component: dyna_comps[1]
            }
        ]),
        ],
        providers: [GlobalService], //- e.g.if your dynamic component needs any service, provide it here.

    })(class { });

this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(dynaModule)
        .then((factories) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < factories.componentFactories.length; i++)
            {
                const f = factories.componentFactories[i];
                this.cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
                this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'DCOMP' + i;                  
            }    
     });
```

For static modules I can lazy load it with router.resetConfig method

```
this.router.resetConfig([
        ...this.router.config,
        {
            path: 'c',
            loadChildren: '../static/static.module#StaticModule'               

        }
    ]);
```

How can I load this JIT compile dynaModule in root module so that I can get the routing done?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " load it in root module?" Are you just trying to create dynamic components? You don't "load" dynamic modules into the root modules. When a dynamic modules is created, it gets created with an entirely separate injector than that of the root injector.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain a bit more of the big picture of what your end goal is or what you want to accomplish with the dynamic component that would help. Even better a StackBlitz with [mcve] would be helpful too.

Comment: Actually, here I created a basic Stack with a dynamic component using JIT for you to update: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-83yzss

Comment: Thanks for the resonse Narm. Basically I have to create an interview app for which I am getting route and html from the server as json object. I want to create new components from that array and have routing implemented. Here is the object that I am getting   [
            { page_route: '/home', page_content: '<div *ngIf = "true"><h4>HOME COMP</h4></div>' },
            { page_route: '/demographics', page_content: '<div *ngIf = "true"><h4>DEMOGRAPHIC COMP</h4></div>' }        
        ];

Comment: Will have an menu list and when the user clicks on the /home link then a new component should be loaded with html content

Comment: <div *ngIf = "true"><h4>HOME COMP</h4></div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171626/discussion-between-user2894836-and-narm).